# Node script with 'type' keyword?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run a node script from the command line (mac), which is throwing an error at this line

```
 type APIOptions = { //<--error
      server?: string,
      feeCushion?: number,
      trace?: boolean,
      proxy?: string,
      timeout?: number
    }
```

Here's the error:

```
type APIOptions = {
     ^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

So what is the deal with this `type` keyword that isn't playing right?

This script is ripple-lib, btw.

Comment: `type`'s contextually reserved ident. would be in ES4. But I think what you want is `interface`... i.e.: `interface APIOptions {...}`, if this is TypeScript and also replace commas with semicolons, because each type trait isn't an statement or list expression.

Comment: It's [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct and might have been done for [Flow](https://flow.org), a  language that attempts to subset JavaScript (version — irrelevantly) with hack-ish compile-time things, like this one of `type`. They call this a transpiler language because its main intention is to convert to compatible JS.x.x.x source code.

Check [this](https://flow.org/en/docs/install/) for transpiling.